# platformio `undefined reference` error when I call esp_camera_init with espidf framework

Tags: c, linker, esp32, platformio, esp-idf

When I call `esp_camera_init` function from this official esp32 camera driver: (https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera), it give me error.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "driver/uart.h"
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"

// LED BUILT-IN
#define BUILT_IN_LED 33

// UART PIN
#define UART_PIN_TXD GPIO_NUM_1
#define UART_PIN_RXD GPIO_NUM_3
#define UART_PIN_RTS UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE
#define UART_PIN_CTS UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE
#define UART_BUF_SIZE 1024

// CAMERA PIN
#define CAM_PIN_PWDN GPIO_NUM_32  // power down is not used
#define CAM_PIN_RESET -1          // software reset will be performed
#define CAM_PIN_XCLK GPIO_NUM_0
#define CAM_PIN_SIOD GPIO_NUM_26
#define CAM_PIN_SIOC GPIO_NUM_27
#define CAM_PIN_D7 GPIO_NUM_35
#define CAM_PIN_D6 GPIO_NUM_34
#define CAM_PIN_D5 GPIO_NUM_39
#define CAM_PIN_D4 GPIO_NUM_36
#define CAM_PIN_D3 GPIO_NUM_21
#define CAM_PIN_D2 GPIO_NUM_19
#define CAM_PIN_D1 GPIO_NUM_18
#define CAM_PIN_D0 GPIO_NUM_5
#define CAM_PIN_VSYNC GPIO_NUM_25
#define CAM_PIN_HREF GPIO_NUM_23
#define CAM_PIN_PCLK GPIO_NUM_22

static uart_config_t konfig_uart = {
    .baud_rate = 115200,
    .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
    .parity = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
    .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
    .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
    .source_clk = UART_SCLK_APB,
};

static camera_config_t konfig_kamera = {
    .pin_pwdn = CAM_PIN_PWDN,
    .pin_reset = CAM_PIN_RESET,
    .pin_xclk = CAM_PIN_XCLK,
    .pin_sscb_sda = CAM_PIN_SIOD,
    .pin_sscb_scl = CAM_PIN_SIOC,
    .pin_d7 = CAM_PIN_D7,
    .pin_d6 = CAM_PIN_D6,
    .pin_d5 = CAM_PIN_D5,
    .pin_d4 = CAM_PIN_D4,
    .pin_d3 = CAM_PIN_D3,
    .pin_d2 = CAM_PIN_D2,
    .pin_d1 = CAM_PIN_D1,
    .pin_d0 = CAM_PIN_D0,
    .pin_vsync = CAM_PIN_VSYNC,
    .pin_href = CAM_PIN_HREF,
    .pin_pclk = CAM_PIN_PCLK,

    .xclk_freq_hz = 20000000,  // EXPERIMENTAL: Set to 16MHz on ESP32-S2 or
                               // ESP32-S3 to enable EDMA mode
    .ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0,
    .ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0,

    .pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG,  // YUV422,GRAYSCALE,RGB565,JPEG
    .frame_size =
        FRAMESIZE_UXGA,  // QQVGA-QXGA Do not use sizes above QVGA when not JPEG

    .jpeg_quality = 12,  // 0-63 lower number means higher quality
    .fb_count =
        1,  // if more than one, i2s runs in continuous mode. Use only with JPEG
    .grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_WHEN_EMPTY  // CAMERA_GRAB_LATEST. Sets when
                                         // buffers should be filled
};

esp_err_t mulai_uart() {
  esp_err_t err =
      uart_driver_install(UART_NUM_1, UART_BUF_SIZE * 2, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
  if (err == ESP_OK) {
    uart_param_config(UART_NUM_1, &konfig_uart);
    uart_set_pin(UART_NUM_1, UART_PIN_TXD, UART_PIN_RXD, UART_PIN_RTS,
                 UART_PIN_CTS);
  }
  return err;
}

esp_err_t mulai_kamera() {
  // initialize the camera
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&konfig_kamera);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    return err;
  }

  return ESP_OK;
}

esp_err_t mulai_led() {
  gpio_pad_select_gpio(BUILT_IN_LED);
  return gpio_set_direction(BUILT_IN_LED, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
}

void app_main() {
  mulai_kamera(); // FOCUS THIS PART, IF I CALL THIS FUNCTION IT WILL GAVE ME ERROR LIKE BELOW
  mulai_led();
  mulai_uart();
  uint8_t i = 0;
  while (1) {
    char teks[2];
    sprintf(teks, "%d", i % 2);
    teks[1] = '\n';
    uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_1, &teks, sizeof(teks));
    gpio_set_level(BUILT_IN_LED, i % 2);
    vTaskDelay(3000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    i++;
  }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
Processing esp32cam (platform: espressif32; board: esp32cam; fram
ework: espidf)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif3
2/esp32cam.html
PLATFORM: Espressif 32 (5.0.0+sha.e66e12c) > AI Thinker ESP32-CAM
HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash
DEBUG: Current (cmsis-dap) External (cmsis-dap, esp-bridge, esp-p
rog, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-
arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa)   
PACKAGES:
 - framework-espidf @ 3.40401.0 (4.4.1)
 - tool-cmake @ 3.16.4
 - tool-esptoolpy @ 1.30300.0 (3.3.0)
 - tool-idf @ 1.0.1
 - tool-mconf @ 1.4060000.20190628 (406.0.0)
 - tool-ninja @ 1.9.0
 - toolchain-esp32ulp @ 1.22851.191205 (2.28.51)
 - toolchain-xtensa-esp32 @ 8.4.0+2021r2-patch3
Reading CMake configuration...
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 1 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
Dependency Graph
|-- esp32-camera @ 2.0.0
Building in release mode
Compiling .pio\build\esp32cam\src\main.o
Linking .pio\build\esp32cam\firmware.elf
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(ov2640.o):(.l
iteral.set_xclk+0x4): undefined reference to `xclk_timer_conf'   
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(ov2640.o): in
 function `set_xclk':
C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pio/libde
ps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/sensors/ov2640.c:502: undefined referenc
e to `xclk_timer_conf'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(esp_camera.o)
:(.literal.camera_probe+0x1c): undefined reference to `camera_ena
ble_out_clock'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(esp_camera.o)
:(.literal.camera_probe+0x20): undefined reference to `camera_dis
able_out_clock'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(esp_camera.o)
: in function `camera_probe':
C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pio/libde
ps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/esp_camera.c:138: undefined refer
ence to `camera_enable_out_clock'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pi
o/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/esp_camera.c:169: undefine
d reference to `camera_disable_out_clock'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pi
o/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/esp_camera.c:198: undefine
d reference to `camera_disable_out_clock'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(esp_camera.o)
: in function `esp_camera_deinit':
C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pio/libde
ps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/esp_camera.c:211: undefined refer
ence to `camera_disable_out_clock'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o):(.
literal.cam_start_frame+0x4): undefined reference to `ll_cam_star
t'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o):(.
literal.cam_start_frame+0x8): undefined reference to `ll_cam_do_v
sync'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o):(.
literal.cam_dma_config+0x38): undefined reference to `ll_cam_dma_
sizes'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o):(.
literal.cam_dma_config+0x3c): undefined reference to `ll_cam_get_
dma_align'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o):(.
literal.cam_init+0x14): undefined reference to `ll_cam_set_pin'  
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o):(.
literal.cam_init+0x18): undefined reference to `ll_cam_config'   
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o):(.
literal.cam_stop+0x0): undefined reference to `ll_cam_vsync_intr_
enable'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o):(.
literal.cam_stop+0x4): undefined reference to `ll_cam_stop'      
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o):(.
literal.cam_deinit+0x0): undefined reference to `ll_cam_deinit'  
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o):(.
literal.cam_config+0x24): undefined reference to `ll_cam_set_samp
le_mode'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o):(.
literal.cam_config+0x28): undefined reference to `ll_cam_init_isr
'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o):(.
literal.cam_task+0x10): undefined reference to `ll_cam_memcpy'   
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o): i
n function `cam_start_frame':
C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pio/libde
ps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:79: undefined reference
 to `ll_cam_start'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pi
o/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:81: undefined re
ference to `ll_cam_do_vsync'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o): i
n function `cam_dma_config':
C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pio/libde
ps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:240: undefined referenc
e to `ll_cam_dma_sizes'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pi
o/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:255: undefined r
eference to `ll_cam_get_dma_align'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o): i
n function `cam_init':
C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pio/libde
ps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:315: undefined referenc
e to `ll_cam_set_pin'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pi
o/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:317: undefined r
eference to `ll_cam_config'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o): i
n function `cam_stop':
C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pio/libde
ps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:329: undefined referenc
e to `ll_cam_vsync_intr_enable'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pi
o/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:329: undefined r
eference to `ll_cam_stop'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o): i
n function `cam_deinit':
C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pio/libde
ps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:425: undefined referenc
e to `ll_cam_deinit'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o): i
n function `cam_config':
C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pio/libde
ps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:343: undefined referenc
e to `ll_cam_set_sample_mode'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pi
o/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:374: undefined r
eference to `ll_cam_init_isr'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o): i
n function `cam_start':
C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pio/libde
ps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:381: undefined referenc
e to `ll_cam_vsync_intr_enable'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: .pio\build\esp32cam\lib3e4\libesp32-camera.a(cam_hal.o): i
n function `cam_task':
C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pio/libde
ps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:134: undefined referenc
e to `ll_cam_stop'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pi
o/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:141: undefined r
eference to `ll_cam_memcpy'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pi
o/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:145: undefined r
eference to `ll_cam_stop'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pi
o/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:147: undefined r
eference to `ll_cam_stop'
c:/users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../
lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/l
d.exe: C:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\cek-kamera/.pi
o/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/driver/cam_hal.c:160: undefined r
eference to `ll_cam_memcpy'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\esp32cam\firmware.elf] Error 1
================== [FAILED] Took 39.57 seconds ==================

 *  The terminal process "C:\Users\User\.platformio\penv\Scripts\
platformio.exe 'run'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Here is my `platfromio.ini`

```
[env]
lib_deps =
  esp32-camera

[env:esp32cam]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32cam
framework = espidf
monitor_speed = 115200
```

Comment: In the cmake, those functions are only included if `IDF_TARGET` is defined to be `esp32` in/for the `CMakeLists.txt` file. Try defining it on the cmake command line

Comment: How do I do define it?

Comment: I've used `cmake` just a tiny bit. You might try: `cmake -DIDF=esp32 ...`. But, it depends upon how `cmake` is invoked. You can do that if you can invoke it manually. I'm unfamiliar with how the esp32-camera project is created. It may be that some other build command is used. You may have to add the definition to some config file (e.g. edit `platformio.ini` or add via `sdkconfig`). I think the project `README.md` file has more information. The quick and dirty way would be to add a `set` command at the top of the `CMakeLists.txt` file. But, I'm sure there are cleaner ways.

Comment: Problem solved, so it's in ```platformio``` side that I should add espidf component in top of my project directory. (https://community.platformio.org/t/linker-error-undefined-reference/28970/3)

Comment: Glad you found that. And, thanks for sharing the solution [I _was_ curious]. I assumed that `platformio` was the [probably] clean way to do it, but didn't connect the dots. I saw the section "Warning about platform.io/espidf and fresh (not initialized) git repos" and adding an explicit version.txt but wasn't sure if it mattered for you. Apparently, the newer git tree allows the version to specified in the `platformio.ini` now. Anyway, go have a coffee--you deserve it :-)